# GSM module L651. So long network registration

Tags: gsm, at-command, quectel

I'm using in my work GSM Module Linq L651. While working, I ran into a problem: the module registers on the network for a very long time. For one minute it found some network, and then it registers on the network for 5 minutes.
There is AT commands example to connect to my server.

```
+CPIN:READY                                                            
OK
//1 minutes left
AT+CSQ                                                                    
+CSQ: 19,99
OK
                                                                   
AT+CFUN=1,1                                                                    
OK
 
//5 minutes left
     
AT+COPS?                                                                 
+COPS: 0,2,"25002", 0
                                                         
AT+CGATT=1                                                                  
+CGATT:1                                                                                                                                  
OK
   
AT+CGACT=0,1                                                                 
OK

AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"                                                  
OK
   
AT+CIPMUX=0                                                                 
OK

AT+CSTT="internet","gdata","gdata"                                            
OK


+CIICR                                                                    
+CSCON: 1                                                                                                                                        
+CSCON: 0                                                                         
COMMAND NO RESPONSE!

AT+CGACT=1,1                                                                 
OK

AT+CIPSTART="TCP","XX.XX.XXX.XX",60001                                       
OK                                                                              
+CSCON: 1
+CSCON: 0                                                                    
+CSCON: 1                                                                    
CONNECT OK
```

I tryed to set some connect modes like `AT+COPS=0` automatic mode.
I use a laboratory power supply for supply, also i have bypass capacitors in supply chain too. So, it is not may be a supply problems.
I also tried different firmware versions. But I didn't get a good result.
What am I doing wrong? A similar module (Quectel BC92) on a similar board works fast.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote to module manufacturer. He answer that i should set network priority before registration:

```
For GSM Priority:
AT+CFUN=0  //set sim minimal functionality
AT+CFGDUALMODE=1,0  ////dual mode single standby+close fastwitch
AT+CFGRATPRIO=2 //GSM priority
AT+CFUN=1 //set sim ful functionality

For NB Priority：
AT+CFUN=0
AT+CFGRATPRIO=4
AT+CFGDUALMODE=1,1
AT+CFUN=1

For NB Only：
AT+CFUN=0
AT+CFGRATPRIO=4
AT+CFGDUALMODE=0
AT+CFUN=1
```

Then need set mode use command `AT+CFGDFTPDN=<mode>` save settings and reeboot module. After that it connect to operator wery fast